# Java cannot find enum in the other class

Tags: java, import, enums

I wrote down a Enum class which could successfully compile, and then whenever I use the Enum class as a type of variable in the other class of the same package, the "cannot find symbol" would occur when compiling.

Here is the code for Enum:

```
package cards;

public enum CardType {
NIGHTMUSHROOM,DAYMUSHROOM,CIDER,BUTTER,PAN,BASKET,STICK
> }
```

And then I use the Enum in another class, I tried to import while the two pieces of code are in the same package so there is no use for the error.

```
package cards;

//import static cards.CardType;

public class Card{
    protected CardType type;
    protected String cardName;

    public Card(CardType newType,String newName){
        this.type = newType;
        this.cardName = newName;
    }

    public CardType getType(){
        return this.type;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.cardName;
    }
}
```

However when I compile Card class, I report the error message like below
[image: Cannot find symbol of enum]

I have looked at some of the questions about enum in the forum while they couldn't make sense for my code.

Comment: Because they are in package `cards` classes `CardType` and `Card` should be in files named `cards/CardType.java` and `cards/Card.java`.

Answer (score -1):

The `CardType` class's full name is `cards.CardType` (it's the package name, plus a dot, plus the classname). Hence, when `javac` is attempting to compile `Card.java`, it looks for the class `cards.CardType`. To find it, it scans the classpath roots for the path `/cards/CardType.class`.

It can't find this file, hence, error.

The 'root' that you need to make this work is **the parent directory** of whereever `Card.java` lives. After all, if you start at that path and 'dir' into `cards` and then look for `CardType.class`, that'll work. It's generally a good idea to stay in this 'root' instead of CDing into subdirs from there.

Hence:

```
cd /home/tianyue/projects/myawesomeproject
ls;     -- prints: "cards"
ls cards;   -- prints: "CardType.java Card.java"
javac cards/CardType.java
javac cards/Card.java
```

Will work fine unless you've been messing with settings and removed `.` as default path. You can always forcibly add it - `javac -classpath . cards/Card.java` instead. Or, much simpler:

```
javac cards/*.java
```

Note that most folks will use a build system such as gradle or maven, or an IDE, to take care of building projects. Once you involve multiple packages and dependencies, trying to command-line your way through a compilation process with just `javac` invokes gets real tedious.

Comment: It does not look for `/cards/CardType.class`, it looks for `cards/CardType.class`. The former would be under the root directory.

Comment: It isn't pedantism. If OP ever tries to use `/cards/CardType.class` instead of `cards/CardType.class` to refer to the file from within their project, it isn't going to work. You can already see from their question that they are using the command line to work on their project. `/cards/CardType.class` is only going to confuse them. I can't understand why you would attack me instead of just removing the one errant character from your answer.

Comment: It's not going to work if you treat it as a file system - for example, if that thing is in a jar. This entire line of reasoning is silly. For example, if you use `MyClass.class.getResource()`, you __must__ use the leading `/`. Your suggestion would not improve the answer at all; I shall not edit it.

Comment: The OP is a beginner who is currently working on their project from the command line. OP doesn't understand things like getResource() yet, and your answer is likely to confuse them.

Comment: It seems to have confused you, that much seems clear. However, the classpath is file-system-esque but crucially isn't _actually_ your file system. You can't `..` your way out of a classpath root. Saying that the right path is specifically `cards/Card.java` in the context of 'The JVM looks for resource X on the classpath is conflating ideas. My answer is 'more correct', in the sense that it operates on the right mental model. I'm not going to change it, as that would create the wrong impression.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers. When I follow the instructions that you provided, just work at the classpath of the src (parent directory of cards) instead of getting into the "cards" dir, the java code could be compiled.